# JodaTime for XML Schema/XACML Duration types

Tags: java, jodatime, duration, xacml

I'm trying to use Joda to support all XACML data times but am having trouble getting it to parse duration from strings like "P50DT4H4M3S". I suspect the problem is ISO and W3C parted ways at some point and Joda supports the ISO path.

In any event, is there an easy way to bridge the gap. I'd like to avoid building my own parser if possible.

I'm aware of javax.xml types, which seems to do what I need, except its based on GregorianCalendar which I'd hoped to avoid by using Joda.

Comment: Durations are independent of calendars. Parse the duration string into linear time (seconds, ms, whatever). You should then be able to use that in date arithmetic with whatever date class / calendar system you want.

Comment: FWIW, the W3C duration appears to be supported by SOAP. See if you can find a SOAP lib for Java and use one of its functions to parse the duration string.  In .NET, I use System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapDuration

Comment: There are lots of packages out there that parse the formats I need; javax.xml.* to name one. Problem is, they don't interoperate with Joda DateTime and many others, which I'm using elsewhere so I really need to make Duration work.

Comment: This works as far as it goes, but I wind up with a PeriodParser and can't find a way to convert that to a Duration. 

PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().
appendSeparator("P").appendDays().appendSeparator("DT").
appendHours(). appendSeparator("H").  appendMinutes().appendSeparator("M").   appendSeconds().appendSeparator("S");
PeriodFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();
PeriodParser parser = builder.toParser();

Comment: So @JodaStephen suggests that Joda's PeriodFormatter already handles the XACML duration string format. Perhaps you could elaborate more on what troubles you were having with Joda and XACML durations?

Comment: The trouble was that Joda uses Period to mean XACML Duration. Handled by using Joda Periods everywhere XACML uses Duration. Parsing now works with one exception; the Oasis Conformance test uses a leading minus in one of its strings which Joda doesn't support. Hacked around it with replace("^-", "") and complementing the result later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`P50DT4H4M3S` is a `Period` in Joda-Time terminology, and can be parsed using `PeriodFormatter`. There are standard parsers in [ISOPeriodFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISOPeriodFormat.html).

Comment: FYI: The XACML 2.0 conformance test IIC003 has one test with a YearMonthDuration of "-P1Y2M" which the joda Period parser doesn't handle. No idea which is wrong; just thought you should know. I hacked around it for now in the Xacml3.0 compiler.

Comment: FWIW this question arose because XACML uses Duration to mean what JodaTime calls Period while providing something entirely different with the name Duration. Aren't standards wonderful? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = ISOPeriodFormat.standard();
Period period = asd.parsePeriod(periodString);
Duration duration = dsa.toStandardDuration();
```